# В моем отношении/в отношении меня

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Вот скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно будет сказать "в моем/его/ее/их отношении" или "в отношении меня/него/нее/них", например, в таком предложении: "В моем отношении/в отношении меня это правило нередко нарушается"?

Comment: В прессе иногда употребляется вариант "в моем/его/ее/их отношении", например(из последних новостей): "Иран пытался обойти экономические санкции, принятые в его отношении" или "Как передает "Интерфакс" со ссылкой на управление СКР по Петербургу, в его [начальника контрольно-ревизионного управления] отношении  возбуждено уголовное дело".  
Я, конечно, в курсе, что ошибки в печати - обычное дело, но бывает ведь все-таки и правильно пишут))).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: >в его [начальника контрольно-ревизионного управления] отношении возбуждено уголовное дело.  
  
А вот это уже, простите, профессиональный жаргон. Настолько въелся, что уже на грани признания его "ограниченно допустимым".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем отношении/в отношении меня - разница в употреблении разных частей речи.В( моем) отношении -сущ."отношение"(в знач."мнение") с предлогом "в", а "в отношении" кого?- меня - предлог "в отношении" с местоимением. Он употребляется только с родит. падежом,указывает на направленность на кого-то, что-то .Есть предлог "по отношению", он требует дат. падежа - "по отношению ко мне".Значение то же - направление действия.

Так что в моём отношении - речь о том, как я отношусь.

Comment: >Так что в моём отношении - речь о том, как я отношусь.

Да, я о таком варианте даже не подумал. Но он возможен только "в моем отношении к чему-то/кому-то".

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет *"в отношении меня/него/её/их"*.  "В моём отношении"  значит, что в вашем отношение к какому-то предмету что-то там (надеюсь, понятно). А в правильном варианте в отношении  *кого* (или по отношению к кому) нарушается правило.

Comment: Вы хотели сказать "в отношении меня/Него/Неё/Них"?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Скопировал из вопроса, не подумав.

Answer (score 2):

Безусловно правильно (с оговоркой на некоторую официальность) "В отношении Имярека Растакого Батьковича". Могу согласиться и с "В отношении меня".
Использование местоимений третьего лица я бы не рекомендовал даже в таком варианте, но не по причине ошибочности, просто они тут плохо воспринимаются на слух.

"В моем (нашем, их, вашем) отношении - в данном контексте грубая ошибка. "В моем отношении" - это только в другом значении. Отношение - устаревшее название письменной просьбы, заявления и проч.